# RawQuery doesn't work when given null valueto args

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

I'm writing a basic android app in which personal information like name, email, etc. is filled in and stored in an SQLite database by pressing a "submit"-button (this all works perfectly). Then there's a search button which should search for a corresponding person in the database when one field is filled in (e.g. only the field name is given a string "harry" and the other fields keep a null-value). This is the corresponding code in my DatabaseHelper class:

```
public Person getPerson(String naam, String adres, String email, String geslacht,
        String leeftijd, String geboortedatum){
    Log.i("Main activity","Person to find: "+naam);
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor curs=db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM personen WHERE (name = ?) OR (adress = ?) "
            + "OR (email = ?) OR (gender = ?) OR (age = ?) OR (birthday = ?)", 
            new String[]{naam, adres, email, geslacht, leeftijd, geboortedatum});
    Log.i("Main activity", "Query works");
```

I used the logs to make sure where the error is thrown and found that the rawQuery does work when all the args[] fields are given a value, but gives an error when one field (e.g. email) contains a null value. Isn't this why I should use the OR statement instead of the AND statement? If not, how can I make it work when not all fields are filled in in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast fix should be to do something like that:

```
new String[]{naam == null? "''":naam, etc}
```

Check if your sting is initialized, if it is not, replace it by a dummy value.

Comment: Why a string containing two quotes?

Comment: you have to put a string with something in the placeholder because if you put an empty string your SQL won't work : WHERE (name = ) will throw an error

Comment: Parameters are not replaced textually; they end up as the value of the SQL expression.

Comment: So you're saying that i have to manually give a parameter, which contains a null value, another string value? otherwise the WHERE clause will always fail to work?

Comment: Thanks, this worked indeed. So to summarize, the SQL will not take null-values and throws an error when one is given to it. If you want the WHERE clause to work, all parameters must have real values.

Answer (score 0):

`rawQuery()` expects a string array, but `null` is not a valid string.

You'd have to put the NULL directly into the SQL string, without a parameter.
But when you're constructing the string dynamically anyway, you can just as well leave out that comparison.

Comment: The error log still says "the bind value at index ... is null" sometimes it says index 4, sometimes 6, etc. Is there something i'm missing here?

Answer (score -1):

search by name:

```
// Getting single contact 
Contact getContact(String name) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
        KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NUM }, KEY_NAME + "=?",
        new String[] { name }, null, null, null, null);
//...
```

for access:

```
Contact contact = null;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
        cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
}
cursor.close();
// can return null if no contact was found.
return contact;
```

Comment: Thanks but that's actually the problem. I want to be able to find a person even when I only know the adress or email..